# Angular 4 router: multiple components loaded in single router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular4-router

I have single `<router-outlet>`, which is defined on a route with multiple child routes. When navigating between these child routes, sometimes (but not always) multiple child route components get loaded into the same `<router-outlet>`.

What can cause this kind of behavior?

Comment: Can you show your code/Plunkr?

Comment: Show your routes.